# Why does Phoenix remove or rewrite headers when handling an Ecto.NoResultsError?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my Phoenix application's controllers I often will use `get!/3` or `get_by!/3` to automatically raise and respond to an `Ecto.NoResultsError`.

I expect `phoenix_ecto`'s protocol to then render my application's `ErrorView`, which it does.

However, in the process, all headers are stripped from my response that were fully available in the `conn` prior to the `Ecto.NoResultsError`. This issue surfaced with a CORS issue, but other headers are removed as well (tested with `put_resp_header`).

It seems odd to me that these headers would suddenly disappear with some implicit behavior. I'm likely going to solve this going forward by handling the not found case myself and using `get/3` and `get_by/3`, but I still would not have expected this behavior to occur.

- Elixir 1.3.3
- Phoenix 1.2.1
- phoenix_ecto 3.0.1

Comment: You are saying that a Repo.get! will modify the conn although Repo is not a Plug !? I also find it very strange... Can you inspect the conn before and after the Repo.get! and print it here to check it out ?

Comment: Are you adding the CORS and other headers (which all disappear) in your controller action or in a separate plug?

Comment: @Dogbert the CORS is being added in a separate Plug.

Comment: This is what's happening in `Plug`: https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/v1.2.2/lib/plug/error_handler.ex#L63

Comment: What is the order about adding the CORS plug and calling `get!/3`?

Comment: @JoshSmith I tried `put_resp_header` in a plug in both my router and endpoint (before the `plug MyApp.Router`) and I don't lose the header if the controller action throws `Ecto.NoResultsError`. Can you post some code about where you're adding the CORS headers exactly?